# What does it mean by prefixing a & to a raw proc object (not lambda) in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, lambda, syntax, proc

I'm using Ruby 2.5 for testing. I have the following code.

```
p = proc {|e| puts e}

def test &b
    b.call 1 if block_given?
end

test &p
```

The output is:

```
1
```

`&b` will make the variable `b` catch the passed in block. But in the demo, I don't have a block. What I have is a raw proc object (not lambda). It seems `&p` converts the proc object back to a block, just as I write `test {|e| puts e}`. Is this ture? What does `&` do here?

Comment: BTW, that `block_given?` check is a bit out of idiom. Since you _are_ capturing the block in the proc `b` (and using `b.call`), it would be more consistent to do `unless b.nil?` or something like that.

Comment: In addition to what @SergioTulentsev mentioned if you were going to use the `block_given?` without the captured block (`&b`) this would generally be written as `def test; yield 1 if block_given? end;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does `&` do here?

Exactly that, convert proc to a block.

> I don't have a block. What I have is a raw proc object (not lambda)

Do you perhaps think these (proc and lambda) are two completely different entities? They're not. They're almost the same thing.

```
proc {} # => #<Proc:0x00007fe50882ecc8@-:1>
-> {} # => #<Proc:0x00007fe50882e840@-:2 (lambda)>
```

Certainly the same thing as far as `&` operator is concerned.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you have any reference material that explains `&`? I can't find it in the document.

Comment: I don't have links to an "official" page, but here's a blog post that looks helpful: https://medium.com/@sihui/proc-code-block-conversion-and-ampersand-in-ruby-35cf524eef55